# Replacing wrongly escaped quotes with sed

Tags: sed

I need to clean a very large CSV, which has wrongly escaped double quotes (`\\"` instead of `\"`). How can I replace all instances of

```
\\"
\\\"
\\\\"
.....
```

with `\"` or just space?

Since it has `\` I asked this question to avoid adding to the mess.

Comment: I'd use perl: perl -pE  's{\\{2,}"}{\\"}g' /tmp/xxx this regex also ignores the good single quotes, so might be faster on a big file.

Comment: @mestia [you may post an answer instead of a comment](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3925/why-are-we-not-encouraging-posting-answers-as-an-answer-but-not-via-comments).

Comment: BTW, generally, in CSV, double quotes are escaped as `""` inside double quotes, not `\"`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas this is the output of `MySQL`.

Comment: AFAIK, the `mysql` client utility has no support for reporting result of queries in csv  format. It can do basic tsv or xml though for which there are tools to convert to other formats like csv.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I gather it mimics the CSV structure by `INTO OUTFILE 'file.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should be enough:

```
sed 's/\\\\*"/\\"/'
```

This replaces a backslash (`\\`) followed by any number of backslashes (`\\*`) and a double quote (`"`), with a backslash followed by a double quote (`\\"`). Use `sed 's/\\\\*"/\\"/g`' for replacing all occurrences in a line.

Answer (score 6):

An alternative if your `sed` supports the `-E` option for extended regexps (this doesn't count the number of backslashes):

```bsh
sed -E 's/[\]+"/\\"/g' file
```